# No overload for 'textBox1_TextChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#

Hello Everyone. This is my first Program and within in 5 minutes I have a error. I've only started to today using C#, so I know I should be really looking around, but I didn't think there was a problem with what I was doing.

My Program is a Generator
depending on what a user picks or types in all the textboxes depends on the outlook of the generated code.

I have two text boxes named: `textBox1`, and `GeneratedCode`

When I press `checkBox1` it allows `textbox1` to be used.

When I press my button it created a string "Testing" (which was to make sure I did it right).

When I pressed F5 to test my build it came back with this error:

```
No overload for 'textBox1_TextChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

I do not know what this means.

Here's my code:

```
    public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            case true:
                {
                    textBox1.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                }
            case false:
                {
                    textBox1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged()
    {

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateBox.Text += "Testing";
    }

    private void GenerateBox_Generated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

This is form1.designer which is in C++:

```
// 
   // textBox1
   // 
   this.textBox1.Enabled = false;
   this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(127, 3);
   this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
   this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(336, 20);
   this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
   this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged); //Error
   // 
   // GenerateBox
   // 
   this.GenerateBox.Enabled = false;
   this.GenerateBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(84, 6);
   this.GenerateBox.MaxLength = 1000000;
   this.GenerateBox.Multiline = true;
   this.GenerateBox.Name = "GenerateBox";
   this.GenerateBox.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
   this.GenerateBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(382, 280);
   this.GenerateBox.TabIndex = 1;
   this.GenerateBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.GenerateBox_Generated);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function textbox1_textChanged should have two arguments as below to be accepted by EventHandler in this case

```
textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `textbox1_TextChanged` method does not match what is expected of the `System.EventHandler` delegate. It should be

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to mark the thread as answered by clicking on the check mark on the left of my answer or Guanxi's answer (you may have to wait a few minutes).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong, you don't have an `EventHandler` called `textBox1_TextChanged`.

Change your `textBox1_TextChanged` method to read:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Why are you handling this event if you aren't actually doing anything here???
    }
```

For the rest of my concern with this question, please refer to the commented portion of my code example.

If you didn't mean to add a handler for this event, just remove the following from your designer code:

```
    textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

Comment: its will be do something thats what im doing now

Comment: Good deal then =)  And yes please mark either Guanxi or keyboardP as the answer.  They were correct, and first =)

Comment: Same issue for:   protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }